# 800xA, assigning and manipulating dates

Tags: date, type-conversion, abb-control-systems

I have a quick question regarding handling of dates and times in 800xA.

What I´m trying to do is to take the current date, add/subtract days and save the result to a new variable.

I´m currently using **`"Date_and_timetocalendarstruct"`**, to split the current date down to **`"current year", "current month"`**, "current week" and so on.

I want to work it like this :

**for example :** take the current date and subtract it by one (or any other number) and thus, generating a new date to store away for future use.

This particular scenario is in ABB,s 800xA systems and its configured against a AC 800M controller.

I have tried a couple of things so for, regarding applying arithmetic operations to dates, but without success.

I hope someone here could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you would have better luck asking here: http://www402.abbext.com/programming-c96342.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think what you missed is the `time` data type.
`date_and_time` is used for a Calendar type of Data while `time` is a time span, e.g. a number of days.

What I understand you want to calculate is (in ST, but works in FBD as well):

`OutDate := sub( InDate, Days);`

Where `OutDate` and `InDate` are of Type `date_and_time` and Days is `time`.
If you specify Days with Value `5d`, you will get `OutDate` as 5 days before `InDate`.

In a similar way, you will get a time span (type `time`) as output when subtracting two `date_and_time` values!